# Pandas columns created function on Groupby sorted columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. What i am trying to do is calculate a column E1 and F1 with a sort and group by then return the entire data frame. The B1 column is incremental, but not necessarily by 1, but the sort on B1 will be

```
A1  B1    C1     D1  
A    8    0.4    1.3
A    1    0.25   1.25   
B    5    0.5    1.02 
C    2    0.32   1.85  
B    1    0.15   1.22  
B    4    0.66   1.97  
B    3    0.29   1.87  
C    1    0.99   1.22  
C    3    0.78   1.39  
C    4    0.65   1.99  
A    2    0.32   1.02
```

if i only had one A1 value like

```
A1  B1    C1     D1  
A    1    0.25   1.25   
A    8    0.4    1.3
A    2    0.32   1.02
```

my workflow is

```
df.sort_values(by=['B1'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

l = df.index.values
for i in range(len(l)):
    tempZ = df.loc[l[i], 'B1'] - df.loc[l[i-1], 'B1']
    tempJ = (df.loc[l [i], 'C1'] - df.loc[l[i-1], 'C1'])
    tempI = (df.loc[l [i], 'D1'] - df.loc[l[i-1], 'D1'])
    *** DO a whole series of mathematical calculations ***
    X = *** Final mathematical calculations ***
    Y = *** Final mathematical calculations ***
    df.loc[l[i], 'E1'] = tempE
    df.loc[l[i], 'F1'] = tempF
```

Which would then output my dataframe as expected

```
A1  B1    C1     D1      E1    F1
A    1    0.25   1.25   7.33   0.33  
A    2    0.32   1.02   7.89   0.12
A    8    0.4    1.3    8.65   0.22
```

But i want to do it for the entire dataframe

```
A1  B1    C1     D1      E1    F1
A    1    0.25   1.25   7.33   0.33  
A    2    0.32   1.02   7.89   0.12
A    8    0.4    1.3    8.65   0.22
B    1    0.15   1.22   12.32  0.77  
B    3    0.29   1.87   1.11   0.12
B    4    0.66   1.97   7.12   0.99
B    5    0.5    1.02   9.25   0.55
C    1    0.99   1.22   2.35   0.123
C    2    0.32   1.85   6.32   1.03 
C    3    0.78   1.39   6.33   1.00 
C    4    0.65   1.99   12.02  0.33
```

So my dataframe needs be grouped by A1 and sorted on B1. the calculations are done on C1 and D1 columns, but also the previous columns.

So i guess my question is, what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this with a large dataframe where i would need to do some type of groupby then output the complete dataframe with the new columns?

Data

```
data = [['A',8,0.4,1.3],['A',1,0.25,1.25],['B',5,0.5,1.02],['C',2,0.32,1.85], 
 ['B',1,0.15,1.22],['B',4,0.66,1.97],['B',3,0.29,1.87],['C',1,0.99,1.22], 
 ['C',3,0.78,1.39],['C',4,0.65,1.99],['A',2,0.32,1.02]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'])
```

EDIT:
The calculations are quite a  bit more complex than i show, i do various operations with the sin,cos, acos, etc and apply calcs on these.  do not believe that diff would really work for me

Comment: can you please provide your data as a csv, for copy paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the following CSV (*saved as test.csv*):

```bash
A1,B1,C1,D1
A,8,0.4,1.3
A,1,0.25,1.25
B,5,0.5,1.02
C,2,0.32,1.85
B,1,0.15,1.22
B,4,0.66,1.97
B,3,0.29,1.87
C,1,0.99,1.22
C,3,0.78,1.39
C,4,0.65,1.99
A,2,0.32,1.02
```

The following code will group on `A1` and sort on `B1`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

res = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns.tolist())
for _, df_chnk in df.groupby('A1', sort=True):
    df_chnk = df_chnk.reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(by=['B1'], ascending=True)
    res = res.append(df_chnk)
res = res.reset_index(drop=True)
print(res)
```

The above code will generate the following dataframe:

```bash
   A1 B1    C1    D1
0   A  1  0.25  1.25
1   A  2  0.32  1.02
2   A  8  0.40  1.30
3   B  1  0.15  1.22
4   B  3  0.29  1.87
5   B  4  0.66  1.97
6   B  5  0.50  1.02
7   C  1  0.99  1.22
8   C  2  0.32  1.85
9   C  3  0.78  1.39
10  C  4  0.65  1.99
```

---

To perform the following operation:

```py
tempZ = df.loc[l[i], 'B1'] - df.loc[l[i-1], 'B1']
tempJ = (df.loc[l [i], 'C1'] - df.loc[l[i-1], 'C1'])
tempI = (df.loc[l [i], 'D1'] - df.loc[l[i-1], 'D1'])
```

Check out [pandas.DataFrame.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html). You can use it on each of the `df_chnk`!

Comment: Does this answer your question? I haven't included the creation of other columns since that seems to be out of scope! With the _grouped and sorted_ dataframe, you can directly compute the new columns without the need for a loop!

Comment: That seemed to solve, and make me feel a bit silly for it being so simple, but i did still need the loop, so the first record wouldn't use the last. so  i needed the range and if  range 0 do something otherwise  proceed with the rest

Comment: The beauty of Python is, we can _do_ otherwise difficult tasks in an **elegant yet simple way**!

Answer (score 1):

I would sorted the values by A and B and then make calculations with groupby and apply, so you have vectorized operations, instead of loops, which are very inefficient:

```py
data = [['A',8,0.4,1.3],['A',1,0.25,1.25],['B',5,0.5,1.02],['C',2,0.32,1.85], 
 ['B',1,0.15,1.22],['B',4,0.66,1.97],['B',3,0.29,1.87],['C',1,0.99,1.22], 
 ['C',3,0.78,1.39],['C',4,0.65,1.99],['A',2,0.32,1.02]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']).sort_values(['A1', 'B1'])
df['new'] = df.groupby('A1').apply(lambda x: ((x['C1'].diff() *  x['D1'].diff()) / x['B1'].mean())).droplevel(0)
df
```

```
   A1  B1    C1    D1       new
1   A   1  0.25  1.25       NaN
10  A   2  0.32  1.02 -0.004391
0   A   8  0.40  1.30  0.006109
4   B   1  0.15  1.22       NaN
6   B   3  0.29  1.87  0.028000
5   B   4  0.66  1.97  0.011385
2   B   5  0.50  1.02  0.046769
7   C   1  0.99  1.22       NaN
3   C   2  0.32  1.85 -0.168840
8   C   3  0.78  1.39 -0.084640
9   C   4  0.65  1.99 -0.031200
```